# QT QItemDelegate, CustomEditor and starting edit on hover

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem that my custom editor opens properly on hovering the cell it is in, however it does not close reliably when the mouse leaves the editor area, resulting in errors when the hover tries to open an editor for the next cell that is beeing hovered.

I wrote my own delegate with its own editor, and would like to start editing cells on hover. To do so I added the following event filter to my delegate:

```
bool starDelegate::eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event) {
    switch(event->type()) {
        case QEvent::MouseMove: {
            QAbstractItemView* table = dynamic_cast<QAbstractItemView*>(watched->parent());

            if(!table) {
                return false;
            }

            QMouseEvent* mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
            QModelIndex index = table->indexAt(mouseEvent->pos());

            if(index.isValid() && index.row() != editRow && index.column() == column) {
                editRow = index.row();
                view->edit(index);
            }
            } break;
        case QEvent::Leave:
            editRow = -1;
            break;
        default:;
    }

    return false;
}
```

While the `editRow` prevents me from opening the Editor multiple times, which results in the error message `edit: editing failed`.

I also close the editor when the mouse leaves the editor (to avoid having to editors open), with the following code:

```
void starEditor::leaveEvent(QEvent* event) {
    (void)event;
    //TODO: hint top/bottom?
    emit closeEditor(this, QAbstractItemDelegate::NoHint);
}
```

I still sometimes get this error message when I move the mouse very quickly. When this is the case I see that the editor was not closed and I keep receiving this error message until I hover over the row that still has the editor open and leave it again so that the code that closes the editor triggers.

I assume the cause is, that the editor misses the `leaveEvent`. How could I remedy this? I.e. how can I know that the Editor I created in `createEditor` still exists, and needs to be closed before I can create a new editor? Or is there a sane way to *reliably* close the editor?